# Eclipse optimized configuration for better performance

Tags: eclipse, performance

Can anyone give an optimized configuration for Eclipse Helios.
I am using XP,i3,3 GB Ram I work mostly on Eclipse and use few lightweighted application along with firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) answer for "optimized" eclipse.ini settings file for Eclipse Helios.